# Saving marker on the map after app closes and retrieving it when opened again

Tags: android, google-maps, sharedpreferences, google-maps-api-2

I am trying to add a marker on a map, close my app, and when opened the marker will be in the position that it was last. I am trying to do this with saved preferences but I am not fully understanding why it does not save.

My code:

```
public void onClickMarker(){

    b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    b1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.parkmycar);
    b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

            Location lastLocation = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            //-----------------------------------------------------------------//
            lat = lastLocation.getLatitude();
            lng =  lastLocation.getLongitude();

            SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("car coordinates",MODE_PRIVATE);
            Editor editor = pref.edit();
            editor.putLong("lat", Double.doubleToLongBits(lat));
            editor.putLong("lng", Double.doubleToLongBits(lng));
            editor.commit();

            SharedPreferences shared = getSharedPreferences("car coordinates",MODE_PRIVATE);
            double myLat = Double.longBitsToDouble(shared.getLong("lat", 0));
            double myLng = Double.longBitsToDouble(shared.getLong("lng", 0));

            //-----------------------------------------------------------------//
            LatLng currLatLng = new LatLng(myLat, myLng);


            if(carLoc!=null){
                carLoc.remove();
            }
            carLoc= map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(currLatLng)
                    .title("your car location")
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.unnamed)));

            map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(currLatLng, 17));
        }
    });
}
```

The method is being called on the onCreate method and when it does place the marker on the current location, but the marker will not be there after the app closes and opens again.

Comment: are you getting lat long values on app restart?

Comment: nah im not getting any values on app restart.

Comment: so it means that your sharedPreferences are not stored with lat long values

Comment: When you get the lat and longitude values, store them in SharedPreferences. Upon app restart check whether any values lat and long are present in SharedPreferences, if present then use them to show the marker.

Comment: @aniruddha Isn't that what I'm doing on my code though?

Comment: Why don't you just store them as `String` rather than `Long`? After retrieving from SharedPreferences convert them to `double`. This work around should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use these methods to save double values in sharedPreferences like this:

```
Editor putDouble(final Editor edit, final String key, final double value) 
{
   return edit.putLong(key, Double.doubleToRawLongBits(value));
}
```

and to retrieve back use this method:

```
double getDouble(final SharedPreferences prefs, final String key, final double defaultValue)
{
    return Double.longBitsToDouble(prefs.getLong(key, Double.doubleToLongBits(defaultValue)));
}
```

Check for the boolean value if you have saved your LatLng's or not:

```
boolean ifSaved = false;

 SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("car coordinates",MODE_PRIVATE);
   Editor editor = pref.edit();
   ifSaved = pref.getBoolean("ifLatLngSaved",true);

   if(ifSaved)
  {
   editor = putDouble(editor,"Lat",myLat);
   editor = putDouble(editor,"Lng",myLng);
   ifSaved = false;
   editor.putBoolean("ifLatLngSaved",ifSaved);     
   editor.commit();
   }
  else
{
  double myPreviousLat = getDouble(pref,"myLat",0);
  double myPreviousLng = getDouble(pref,"myLng",0);
}
```

Comment: for the get doouble method, what does the 0 param do?

Comment: That is actually a default value you pass if the sharedpreference returns null @guevarak12

Comment: the 0 param is leading me to the actual coordinates 0,0 and not my last saved coordinate

Comment: set a boolean value as you save your coordinates and next time check for the same boolean values to get previous coordinates @guevarak12

Answer (score 0):

You did

- Getting lat&lng from Location service
- Putting lat&lng to SharePreferences
- Getting lat&lng from SharePreferences

So I think you always get the new lat&lng from Location service, not lat&lng that you put in SharePreference

You should

- Getting lat&lng from SharePreferences
- If they're equal 0 -> get lat&lng from Location service
- Creating a marker with lat&lng, then show intto map
- Putting lat&lng to SharePreferences

Answer (score 0):

I made it saving latitude an longitude to Strings, my save method :

```
    String latitude = String.valueOf(lat);
    String longitude = String.valueOf(lng);
    editor.putString("latitude", latitude);
    editor.putString("longitude", longitude);
```

Then get them in my get method :

```
    String latitude = preferences.getString("latitude", "");
    String longitude = preferences.getString("longitude", "");
    lat = Double.parseDouble(latitude);
    lng = Double.parseDouble(longitude);
```

This works fine for Me.